# Can i list files on the local folders when lftp the mobile phone?

Tags: ftp

I can link my android phone from pc in lan(suppose it is 192.168.30.30):

```
lftp  192.168.30.30  #link android phone from pc
ls
```

The command `ls` show all files and folders in the android phone,can i list files on the pc(local in the title) in lftp's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can I list files on the pc (local in the title) in `lftp`'s console?

Yes.

```
local ls
```

Source: [LFTP - the manual page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)